# Jordan decomposition of sum of two measures

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, measure-theory

Let $\mu$ and $\nu$ be finite signed measures. Then by the Jordan Decomposition Theorem, we can write $\mu = \mu^{+} - \mu^{-}$ and $\nu = \nu^{+} - \nu^{-}$ where $\mu^{\pm}, \nu^{\pm}$ are unsigned measure. Consider $\lambda := \mu + \nu$. This is also a signed measure. Then we again have $\lambda = \lambda^{+} - \lambda^{-}$ for some unsigned measures $\lambda^{\pm}$. Is $\lambda^{+} = \mu^{+} + \nu^{+}$?

Comment: Doesn't the theorem gurantee that the decompositon is unique

Comment: Is it true that $\mu^{+} + \nu^{+}$ is mutually singular to $\mu^{-} + \nu^{-}$? Because it if was, then indeed the uniqueness in the decomposition theorem would imply this result. However, I do not know how to answer this.

Comment: I studied this last semester and I feel I forgot it.

Comment: I will try to get back to you after I revise.

Answer (score 3):

No, not in general. For example, consider three unit point masses $\delta_a$, $\delta_b$, $\delta_c$ and let $\mu= \delta_a-\delta_b$, $\nu = \delta_b-\delta_c$. Then $\mu+\nu = \delta_a-\delta_c$. Thus,
$$\mu^+ = \delta_a,\quad \nu^+ = \delta_b, \quad (\mu+\nu)^+ = \delta_a\ne \mu^++\nu^+$$